# need helping displaying table

Tags: reactjs, api

My code works fine and I can display one record.

```js
import react from "react";

export default class App extends react.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    person: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "API goes here";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ person: data[0], loading: false });
    console.log(data[0]);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading || !this.state.person ? (
          <div>loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <div>{this.state.person.firstName}</div>
            <div>{this.state.person.lastName}</div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I display the data into a table and be able to edit it as well. I also want to be able to edit all fields. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done three changes here. One in the state and two in the body. I have also updated your question to be formatted correctly.

**Also:** Change `react` to `React`!

```js
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    person: []        /* 1. Changed it as an array. */
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e9ef690435f5604bb4567dd";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ person: [...data], loading: false });
    console.log(data[0]);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* 2. Change the condition for loading here... */}
        {this.state.loading || this.state.person.length === 0 ? (
          <div>loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <>
            {/* 3. Change the things here in tabular form. */}
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>firstName</th>
                <th>lastName</th>
                <th>dob</th>
              </tr>
              <tbody>
                {this.state.person.map((person, key) => (
                  <tr key={key}>
                    <td>{person.title}</td>
                    <td>{person.firstName}</td>
                    <td>{person.lastName}</td>
                    <td>{person.dob}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Working Snippet:** https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-diffie-989pr

**Demo:** https://989pr.csb.app/

**Preview:**

[image: preview]

**Stack Snippet**

I have made a lot of changes to make it run on Stack Snippet. But please refer to the above Code Sandbox Link.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    person: [] /* 1. Changed it as an array. */
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e9ef690435f5604bb4567dd";
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => this.setState({ person: [...data], loading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* 2. Change the condition for loading here... */}
        {this.state.loading || this.state.person.length === 0 ? (
          <div>loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {/* 3. Change the things here in tabular form. */}
            <table border="1" cellPadding="5">
              <tr>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>firstName</th>
                <th>lastName</th>
                <th>dob</th>
              </tr>
              <tbody>
                {this.state.person.map((person, key) => (
                  <tr key={key}>
                    <td>{person.title}</td>
                    <td>{person.firstName}</td>
                    <td>{person.lastName}</td>
                    <td>{person.dob}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @user14601857 You can try updating the object that you receive. What do you wanna edit?

Comment: @user14601857 You should be able to do it using a package like [React Table Editable - Bootstrap 4](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/editable/). Please check it out, go through the docs and let me know if you need a hand in it? At the same time, you have to implement API endpoints for editing purposes.